# LINQ-XML How should I get the error XML node with given error attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Here is the XML

Get this ResultCode attribute, if error then look for all product's child nodes

```
   <PRODUCT Action="Result" ResultCode="ERROR" ResultText="An error occurred in a child   element.">            <PNO>9723151113</PNO>
       <CATALOG_NO ResultCode="ERROR" ResultText="Invalid entry for this field.">1134</CATALOG_NO>
   </PRODUCT>
```

So first I want to check wheather any node's attribute has ERROR , then select child node and look   for descendent child node has error and get that node using LINQ.
As above,look for all the nodes under Cust to check for attribute 'ResultCode', if it has Error  value then select that node and look for thier child nodes to find out exact error.
      Cust -> any node with error ? -> product => select product => look all child nodes under      product   => select ERROR attribute node.

I don't want to put a logic which wil parse each and every node in loop, so thinking linq to use would be easy .Any idea how to achive this using Linq query?

Comment: im not very good in xpath but i think you could use some Expression like //Product[@ResultCode="Error"]/CATALOG_NO[@ResultCode="Error"] With this Expression and an xpath-parser (there's one in .NET) you can get the nodes you want.

Comment: but the problem is, error can happen at any node,not just product.I have not mentioned entire XML since it is big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"YourXML.xml");
var xElementWithErrors = (from xElem in doc.Descendants()
                          where xElem.Attribute("ResultCode").Value == "ERROR"
                          select xElem).ToList();
```

All child with of Product tag with ResultCode of "ERROR" will be populated into the list `xElementWithErrors`.

Answer (score 0):

Using XDocument you could first check for any node with an attribute value of `ERROR` and then  also select its parents like this

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(...);

var result = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(n => n.Attribute("ResultCode").Value == "ERROR")
    .Select(n => new { n.Parent, ActualNode = n });
```

You may want to check if `Parent` is not null and also filter on the type of node you actually don't want to process.  Without knowing more about what your are trying to achieve here it's hard to help you more.  Hopefully, this will get you started.

Comment: I think the check should be if `ResultCode==ERROR`. Otherwise, you're just making a very opaque search for any `ERROR` text. Granted, not many field values say `ERROR`, but being more logically precise is good, not bad.

Comment: You are right.  I missed that in the original question.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct you only want to get the innermost elements that have an attribute `ResultCode="ERROR"`.
For your sample data `<PRODUCT>` should not be in the result since it has a child element with `ResultCode="ERROR"`.

The [`Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb346432.aspx) method returns all descendant elements in the document. Filtering by the attribute solely would therefore include the `<PRODUCT>`node. So you need to add a check for the children of each element:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Test.xml");

var errors = doc.Descendants()
                .Where(e => e.Attribute("ResultCode") != null &&
                            e.Attribute("ResultCode").Value == "ERROR" &&
                            !e.Elements().Any(c => c.Attribute("ResultCode") != null &&
                                                   c.Attribute("ResultCode").Value == "ERROR"));
```

This will return only those elements that do not have any children with an error.

Please note that the check for null can be omitted if each node in your XML has a `ResultCode` attribute. If not you would otherwise get a `NullReferenceException`. I would suggest to write a little helper method for that check:

```
public static bool HasError(XElement element)
{
    var resultCode = element.Attribute("ResultCode");
    return resultCode != null && resultCode.Value == "ERROR";
}

var errors = doc.Descendants()
                .Where(e => HasError(e) && !e.Elements().Any(c => HasError(c)));
```

Please also note that this will return elements that have `ResultCode="ERROR"` even if their parents don't have an error.

If your requirements are that an element should only be included in the result if its parent also has an error and if you are not sure that the XML will always be formed like that you will need to write a recursive function:

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> InnermostErrors(XElement root)
{
    var resultCode = root.Attribute("ResultCode");
    if (resultCode == null || resultCode.Value != "ERROR")
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var childrenWithError = root.Elements().Where(e => HasError(e));
    if (!childrenWithError.Any())
    {
        yield return root;
    }

    foreach (var inner in childrenWithError.SelectMany(e => InnermostErrors(e)))
    {
        yield return inner;
    }
}
```